# How does q cache data?

Tags: kdb

I was trying to measure data access times for a db I had created. It was taking ~1s for one day's data. To aggregate I ran the following code. I am using kdb studio and there are ~1MM trades in total every day

```
\t ans: raze {select from trade where date=x, sym=`ABC} each 20#dtl
```

dtl was the entire list of dates. I closed the server and ran it again and surprisingly this took <1 second. As this was contrary to what I had observed above, I ran this

```
\t ans: raze {select from trade where date=x, sym=`ABC} each 20#20_dtl
```

and now it took ~21 seconds. My question is if i close the kdb server, is it possible for q to still cache some of the previous results?

Comment: When you say you closed the server, do you mean you dropped the connection and then reconnected or did you actually kill your HDB and then start it up again?

Comment: killed my HDB and started again but good point :). could it be an os page file/ caching issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDB+ does not cache anything. It's all hardware caching if you see a difference in speed like this. You can confirm this if you flush the cache (in unix systems there are a set of commands to do this, but you'll need root access). Bottom line is that KDB+ doesn't do any caching at all. (unless you tell it to of course... a la .Q.fu)

As an aside, not sure how your query worked here - 20#dtl will give a list of dates, and date=x would then give a length error. I assume you meant "date in x". In which case you may get skewed results due to multithreading, if you're using -s on the command line.

Comment: i'm doing an each for dtl

Comment: checked it in linux. its hardware cache. you can check by restarting kdb and doing `sync and `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to your operating system caching the data it reads from disk. Kdb+ provides no inbuilt caching by default.

Comment: That is my guess too but unless there is a way to find that with some certainty it is just a guess. could be something else too

Comment: If it's a linux box, and you have priviledge access (root/sudo) can use following command to flush + purge caches:

`sync ; sudo echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`